# chrome exit shortcut ctrl shift q not working

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and google chrome but I find the exit shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> not working and has no effect.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you please go through the keyboard short-cuts in the Control Center (`gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts`) to check if the same short-cut is already taken? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the shortcut was requested in Chromium bugs, and it looks like the request was finally fulfilled:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243164

You can join those that are now requesting it as a customization flag. Otherwise, looks like you'll have to make a custom shortcut.

Comment: Google attacks Linux users yet again. ☹

Comment: I just starred the bug requesting (at least) a flag/toggle to get the old behavior: https://crbug.com/903990
(For me: `<Ctrl+Shift+q>` was already the "safe" version of `<Ctrl+q>`)

Comment: And how do I get that Ctrl-Shift-Q shortcut back? I find this change extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is because I have the habit of setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to Close Window, setting this back to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> would make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> work in chrome. But I had this setting successfully working with chrome in KDE. Don' know if it is a bug, though.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes current window, so if there's only one window open, it exits Chromium.